# swift ios why use didSet in this example

Tags: ios, swift, didset

I am trying to understand why didSet it used in this example. Its a piece from a pagecontroller that displays images (image slider)

Code:

```
import UIKit

class PageItemController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Variables
    var itemIndex: Int = 0
    var imageName: String = "" {

        didSet {

            if let imageView = contentImageView {
                imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
            }

        }
    }

    @IBOutlet var contentImageView: UIImageView?

    // MARK: - View Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(imageName)
        contentImageView!.image = UIImage(named: imageName)

    }
}
```

I have tried the same code but wihtout the `didSet` and I dont notice any changes in speed etc, so why is it used?

Comment: It works as expected during the first load. However, if you remove didSet and there is no additional code doing that then when imageName is changed, your image won't be changed. didSet makes sure when imageName is changed, also changing the actual image. Otherwise the code changing the imageName should be also responsible of changing the actual image. Of course, if you image is ever change during the view lifetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `didSet` will set the uiimage with `imageName` string if `imageName` is set.
If you are assigning imageName from anyother view then, You should use the code like :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use didSet you can change your displayed Image by setting `imageName`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather use this: 
`let image = UIImage(named: "*Name of image in assets*")`
 and make sure the actual image is in the project assets.